# Multivariate prediction model using R

Tags: r, predictive-modeling, forecast

Imagine having a large database coming from a super market chain with panel data, whose cross-section variables are the different products sold in each super-market. The frequency is daily, that is you have one value for each product sold in each super-market per day. 
Beyond their own history, you have the time-series of other variables e.g. dummy variables that signal the existence of offers.

Your objective is to predict the number of goods sold for each product in each super-market.

**Which functions would you use in R to make a week-ahead multivariate forecast?** 
Which approach would you suggest?

Comment: Kaggle recently had a [Rossmann](http://blog.kaggle.com/?s=Rossmann) store challenge, which was at the store level (not product) but some of the interviews might be good to browse.

Comment: Waaaay too broad a question. GLM. RandomForest. Neural Network. Time Series analysis. Kalman FIltering dynamic regression... This is more like an essay question than something that can be answered here.

Comment: These are answers to the second question, I would like to know which functions you would use in each case!

Comment: There's probably several packages for each of those approaches. Do some research by reading the R Task Views on such things. e.g.:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html

Comment: I already did this and didn't find it useful as far as a number of the techniques you mentioned are concerned and in particular neural networks.

Comment: "Which approach should I use?" There are entire **books** written on multivariate forecasting, and in them you may find the answer to your "which approach?" question. Without data, or context, all we can do (and I've done it in comments) is spew all the techniques we know and say "now you go figure it out".

Answer (score 0):

You could try also  R  [h2o](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/h2o.pdf)

You  have implementations  for   random forest,   gbm , linear models and also   deep  learning .
THe  advantage is  that    h2o is pretty   fast  compared  to   other  implementations

Comment: Thanks Daia, I am aware of h2o and indeed it seems very powerful